# padding setting for password field

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am using Swift 3. I have two txtFields, one of them for email, the other one for password. I use the following code to give the email field a padding:

```
txtEmail.leftView = paddingView;
txtEmail.leftViewMode = .always
```

However, the app seems to run into an infinity loop when I apply the same to the password field:

```
txtPassword.leftView = paddingView;
txtPassword.leftViewMode = .always
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Where are you putting this code?

Comment: Do you create new/different paddingView or use this same in two fields?

Comment: I put in in viewWillAppear and it is the same paddingView for both fields: `let paddingView = UIView(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 30))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This UITextField extension will ease your implementation later on and should solve any problems related to using the same UIView on multiple textfields:

```
extension UITextField {
    func pad(_ amount: Int) {
        self.leftView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: amount, height: self.frame.height))
        self.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.always
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this in `viewDidLoad` or anywhere lower in the view controller's call hierarchy

```
txtEmail.pad(15)
txtPassword.pad(15)
```

Answer (score 0):

As your code display you are using same view object for both textfield at the same time and may be that's why your app is looping. you can not add same view object as a subview for two diffrent textfield at the same time. so create new view instance and set it as a padding for individual textfiled.

```
  let paddingForEmail = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 15,txtEmail.frame.size.height))
    //Adding the padding to the Email textField
    txtEmail.leftView = paddingForFirst
    txtEmail.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode .Always

    //Create new padding object of view for second textField
    let paddingForPassword = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 15,txtPassword.frame.size.height))

    //Add padding to the Password textField
    txtPassword.leftView = paddingForPassword
    txtPassword.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode .Always
```

hope this will help you.